Как выводить ошибки формы через модальное окно
Заранее извиняюсь, не кидайтесь помидорами, под конец недели уже голова закипает. В js и php не профи.
Есть форма:
<?
if (isset($_POST['reg'])) {
    $user_id = $_POST['user'];
        
    $querycs = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = '$user_id' LIMIT 1");
    $countcs = mysqli_num_rows($querycs);
    if ($countcs > 0) {
        $rowcs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querycs);
        $a = ($rowcs['a']);
        $b = ($rowcs['b']);
        $c = ($rowcs['c']);
        $d = ($rowcs['d']);
        $user_set = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE `persons` SET user_id='$user_id', a=a+'$a', b=b+'$b', c=c+'$c', d=d+'$d' WHERE username='$username'");
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=account.php" />';
        exit;
    }else {
    echo '<div class="error">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Please, tap the character you want to choose!
                  </div>';

    }
}
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
    <center><input style="width:50%;" type="submit" name="reg" value="Registration" class="btn btn-success btn-lg col-12"></center>
</form>

как вместо обычной ошибки, которая выводиться через div вывести ошибку в модальном окне?

Что есть - модальное окно? Как вы себе это видите и представляете?

обычное всплывающее окно (pop-up), по центру экрана.

Я думаю, автору нужна функция alert(), которая идеально подходит к этому говнокоду
